# rust deferencing and mutable variables

Tags: rust

I am very new to Rust, so forgive me if the question is obvious.

How does rust dereferencing work? Please see below example.

I am reading a book about rust and I found the following example with an explanation regarding the use of  `&` in the vector variable of `numbers[1...]`. It says that it is used to "borrow its elements for the loop". Can anyone explain what that means in terms of memory and what is actual difference vs not using `&` sign?

The second question was regarding `*m` operator, where it says "it lets `m` borrow each element in succession, the * operator deferences m, yielding the value it refers to". Does it mean that `*m` will exhaust the variable and will no longer be available?

```
fn main() {
    let mut numbers = Vec::new();

    for arg in env::args().skip(1) {
        numbers.push(u64::from_str(&arg)
            .expect("error parsing argument"));
    }

    if numbers.len() == 0 {
        eprintln!("Usage: gcd NUMBER ...");
        std::process::exit(1);
    }

    let mut d = numbers[0];
    for m in &numbers[1..] {
        d = gcd(d, *m);
    }

    println!("The greatest common divisor of {:?} is {}",
    numbers, d);

}


fn gcd(mut n: u64, mut m: u64) -> u64 {
    assert!(n != 0 && m != 0);
    while m != 0 {
        if m < n {
            let t = m;
            m = n;
            n = t;
        }
```

Comment: Did you read [references and borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html) in the Rust book? I can recommend it, it has a lot of good information about those topics.

Comment: thank you, it's perfect resource!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me recommend the ["References and Borrowing"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html) section in the Rust book. It has a lot of good information about this topic.

First, the easy question:

> Does it mean that *m will exhaust the variable and will no longer be available?

The `*` operator indeed dereferences until you are at the actual object. For example, look at the following code. I use `String` here because it isn't `Copy`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = String::from("aaa.");
    let x_ref = &x;
    *x_ref;
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*x_ref` which is behind a shared reference
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     *x_ref;
  |     ^^^^^^ move occurs because `*x_ref` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Note that we don't do anything with `*x_ref`; the act of dereferencing alone is already enough for the compiler to complain. Dereferencing would indeed consume the object, but you can't move an object out of a reference, so the compiler complains.

Note that in your loop, the `*m` works without a problem. That's because `u64` implements `Copy`, which means anything that would move the `u64` away instead performs a copy.

The other question is a little harder:

> It says that it is used to "borrow its elements for the loop".

Yes and no; loops are actually a bit unintuitive to be honest. It's more complicated behind the scenes than the beginner tutorials reveal, and explaining it in detail would be too much for this post.

Just as a quick teaser: `&numbers[1..]` actually creates a `&[u64]` slice into the `numbers` array. `for` then calls [`into_iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#impl-IntoIterator-for-%26%27a%20%5BT%5D) on that slice, which consumes the slice and returns an iterator that produces `&u64` elements. The `for` loop then uses this iterator to loop.

What might probably help you most is if you read the [section about slices](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html) in the Rust book. That should give you an initial idea, and if you still struggle with some details, you can open a new, more specific question on SO.